# Conditional logic for coding questions?

Tags: python

If the user typed in 'N' for no, how would you avoid the extra cost of $50 and skip asking for the height and width to calculate the surface area, and carry on with the rest of the code? Bare in mind that I haven't written the questions after the code; if the user typed 'Y' for Yes, then the $50 will be added and the program will ask for the width and height of each wall in the room.

```
total_surface_area = 0
number = int(input("Number of rooms to paint")
print("\n***ROOM DETAILS***")
for room in range(number):
    room_name = input("\n\nPlease enter the name of the room:")
    wall_number = int(input("Number of walls in the room:"))
    wallpaper = input("\nWould you like to remove the paint? (Y for Yes/N for No). If yes, $50 will be charged per room:")
```

Comment: `if wallpaper == 'N' `  is a good start

Comment: Put them in conditional statements?? `if wallpaper == 'N': ... elif wallpaper == 'Y': ...`??

Answer (score 0):

You were probably a bit too vague for us to determine what the most elegant solution to your problem is, but I suspect you were looking for the `continue` and `break` statements. You can find an explanation [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm).

This might illustrate how you can use both statements:

```
total_surface_area = 0
# You were missing a parenthesis in the following line.
number = int(input("Number of rooms to paint"))
print("\n***ROOM DETAILS***")
for room in range(number):
    print('=== details of room number '+str(room)+' ===')
    room_name = input("\n\nPlease enter the name of the room:")
    wall_number = int(input("Number of walls in the room:"))

    print("\nWould you like to remove the paint? (Y for Yes/N for No). If yes, $50 will be charged per room:")
    while True:
        buffer = input()
        if buffer == 'Y':
            wallpaper = True
            break
        elif buffer == 'N':
            wallpaper = False
            break
        else:
            print('please anser "Y" or "N"')

    if wallpaper:
        print('I will now ask many more questions.......')
        # continue asking questions ...
    else:
        # move to the next room
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
from distutils.util import strtobool
total_surface_area = 0
extra_cost = 0
number = int(input("Number of rooms to paint")
print("\n***ROOM DETAILS***")
for room in range(number):
    room_name = input("\n\nPlease enter the name of the room:")
    wall_number = int(input("Number of walls in the room:"))
    wallpaper = input("\nWould you like to remove the paint? (Y for Yes/N for No). If yes, $50 will be charged per room:")
    if strtobool(wallpaper):
        extra_cost += 50
        dimensions = []
        for wall in range(wall_number):
            dimensions.append(input("Please input wall dimensions..."))

    ...
```